std::ofstream open sucess,but when i call write got a error "no such file or directory"
I have cpp code like this:
std::ofstream fs;
queue msg_queue;
uint64_t write_size_in_shared_memery =0;
string file_name = "1";
while(true)
{
    buffer,buffer_size = msg_queue.pop();
    if(!buffer)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(!fs.is_open())
    {
        fs.open(file_name, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if(!fs)
        {
            printf("open error ");
            continue;
        }
    }

    if(!fs.write(buffer, buffer_size))
    {
        // error happend from this line
        std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    write_size_in_shared_memery = fs.tellp();
    if(!fs.good() || fs.tellp() > max_file_size)
    {
        fs.close();
        file_name += 1;
        fs.open(file_name, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
    }
}

but I got a error "no such file or directory" in linux system.
I want to known what reason can let this error happend, From what I understand, deleting an already open file does not actually delete it, but merely removes its link from the file system. So I should still be able to write to it normally even after deleting it.And I try to remove file in test this error not happend.
so Can any other reason will be cause this error?
I made a test code,when open file sucess sleep thread, i removed this file,continue thread try write this file,write sucess and not any error happend.

Your working directory is likely not what you think.

What does deleting an already open file have to do with your problem? Did you stop the program and delete the file from outside the program?

Are you sure are running exactly same code as you showing us? There is no other IO operations running which could override value of errno?

fstream::write is not documented to set errno. The stream has its own state flags.

@BoP when std::ios_base::badbit is set also errno is set to respective value. I do not think write function can set other flags.

ZHU PEI: Is this really the code that generates the error? Please fill in the blanks by making it a [mre].

Can you run exactly this code on your machine and then come back with its output. There is no way to reproduce error you are reporting without knowing what is wrong with your code or machine.

sorry this problem cannot be reproduced， and I supplement the code where the reasoning is problematic to bring it closer to more realistic code

@ZHUPEI again provide [mcve]. Can I just copy paste code you provided and compile it without modification? NO!

buffer,buffer_size = msg_queue.pop(); does not assign to buffer. It is equivalent to buffer; buffer_size = msg_queue.pop();. And file_name += 1 adds the (unprintable) character with encoding 1 to the string. It is most likely not a valid character in your file system.

fs.write() will return a reference to fs, regardless of failure. Testing that like a boolean will yield the result of operator ! on fs.
As for what's going on, you might want to call fs.is_open() after the call to fs.open(): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream.
I suspect that the errno value you're looking at isn't what you're interested in. Maybe take a look at fs.rdstate() instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate

"fs.write() will return a pointer to fs" - No, it won't. "Testing that like a boolean will not yield a meaningful result." - It would if write would set the failbit on failure, but it won't.

it returns reference to stream and this is converted to bool by https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

my mistake, I see write would not set the failbit, but if failbit set by open the should not print "no such file or directory", still confuse...

@ZHUPEI Please update your question with a [mre]. The current code can't be compiled and also contains a lot of totally unrelated things.

Thanks @TedLyngmo, I have edited the answer to be more accurate to the docs.
